# POST request works in localhost but not working after deploying to the google cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, google-cloud-platform

Axios post request is working fine on my local server but it is throwing a 404 not found error after deploying the project on Google Cloud.

In the localhost, all the requests are sent to the URL starting with `http://localhost:9000/api/...` and it handles all the post requests perfectly without any problem.

But, after deploying the project on the Google cloud it throws a `404 error`.
I have configured NGINX to redirect the incoming request to the server if the URL contains `/api/...`  and a complete `URL`  looks like this `https://myurl.org.nz/api/...`. Below is my Nginx config.

**Code:**

```
server {
  server_name myurl.org.nz www.myurl.org.nz;
  location / {
    root /home/myproject/build/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
  }
}
```

my server-side code that handles the incoming request

`base.routes.js`

```js
router.route("/").post(async (req, res) => {
  await axios
    .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json", {
      params: {
        query: req.body.query.search,
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY,
      },
    })
  // ........ rest of the code.....
})
```

server.js

```js
const route = require("./Routes/base.routes");
app.use("/api", route);
```

The Axios request sent to the server from the client. `REACT_APP_PROD_URL=https://www.myurl.org.nz/api/`

```js
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_URL}`, data)
  .then((res) => {
    setData(res.data)
  })
```

I am not sure where I am wrong. Any help is appreciated and please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

here is a super super basic app that supports multiple routes and your code

```js
// ./index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)

app.use('/', require('./routes'))

server.listen('3000', () => {
  console.log('running on port 3000')
})
```

```js
// ./routes/index.js
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

// responds to GET http://localhost:3000
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    root: {
      api: 'basic api',
      version: 1
    }
  })
})

router.use('/api', require('./api'))

module.exports = router
```

```js
// ./routes/api.js
const axios = require('axios')
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

// responds to POST http://localhost:3000/api
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios
      .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json", {
        params: {
          query: req.body.query.search,
          key: process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY,
        },
      })
    console.log(response)
    // ........ rest of the code.....
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    })
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

and some ngninx code

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_nodejs_server;
    root /home/myproject/build;

    location / {
        more_clear_headers Server;
        server_tokens off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @alilland, thank you very much for your answer. I have fixed the issue by removing the forward / from proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/. I really appreciate your time taken to answer my question.

Comment: @ksa also, be sure to run your server with something like PM2, otherwise if and when when your app crashes it will never restart

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by removing the forward / from proxy_pass localhost:9000.